# How to get the right Data to an external URL and the right ID through the API?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, metadata

is there a possibility to get more informations to a specific url e.g. preview image, title and short description through the open graph? If you do something like this, you only get the "shares" //graph.facebook.com/http://www.google.de

It's a bit confusing, when I get the ID via FQL through the object_url Table I get a different ID to the ID I get from the Debugger.

Getting the ID:

//graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,id,type,site%20FROM%20object_url%20WHERE%20url%20=%20%22http://google.de%22

```
Result: "id": 6319338796</pre>
Trying to get the Data with that ID failed (acces token needed)
```

//graph.facebook.com/6319338796/

```
 "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
```

Get the ID with the Debugger:

//developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.de

Getting the Result from ID 438699604740 (no problem):
//graph.facebook.com/438699604740

```
{
"url": "http://www.google.de/",
"type": "website",
"title": "Google",
"image": [{"url": "http://www.google.de/images/google_favicon_128.png"}
],
"updated_time": "2012-12-19T15:26:32+0000",
"id": "438699604740"
}
```

I am just wondering, why there are two different object IDs for the same URL and why do I need for the one an acces_token and not for the other?

The question is, how to get the right Data and the right ID throug the API? Or are there any restrictions to get these Data from a URL?

Thanks for help!